# joomla to wordpress htaccess 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

I got one simple .htaccess not working, i'm searching for a clue to solve it

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/orario-corsi-via-piacenza http://www.esperienzadanza.it/2016/contatti/
```

redirects good

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/corsi/gioco-danza-3-5-anni http://www.esperienzadanza.it/2016
Redirect 301 /index.php/maestri-e-collaboratori/raffaele-lele-angius-hip-hop ...nzadanza.it/2016/raffaele-angius/
```

they redirect bad to

```
...nzadanza.it/2016/orari-2/gioco-danza-3-5-anni
...nzadanza.it/2016/raffaele-lele-angius-hip-hop
```

I really  don't know why and since I'm a novice in it I ask your help even to learn something, sorry for the simple question.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Please format your code properly, you have two Redirect statements behind each other in the same line

Comment: Code formatting for quoted .htaccess sections. Added tags joomla and wordpress.

Comment: Hi Davide, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you explain your problem a little bit more? If you made it more clear exactly what you want the .htaccess to do versus what it is doing, it will be easier for people to understand your question and provide a solution.

Comment: Thank you in advance guys, i try to explain: since I'm novice I don't have permission to write more than two links.

Comment: Thank you in advance guys, i try to explain: since I'm novice I don't have permission to write more than two links.
I want to redirect from (joomla based) to wordpress 
Redirect 301 /index.php/maestri-e-collaboratori/raffaele-lele-angius-hip-hop http://www.esperienzadanza.it/2016/raffaele-angius/
This line seems to work alone, but I find out that when i add the homepage redirect line:
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.esperienzadanza.it/2016/
it doesn't work anymore and redirects to http://www.esperienzadanza.it/2016/raffaele-lele-angius-hip-hop which doesn't exist. Thanks in advance. D

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the very beginning of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://esperie...it/2016
```

The above should work. I don't know what your website is about and that's why I didn't include the full link (so just replace ... with the remaining part of your domain) .